# ng-bind not showing content of div while loading

Tags: angularjs

I'm confused as to why ng-bind isn't showing the content of "Loading..." while the $scope is binding the variable. According to the documentation on ng-bind the element contents should be displayed until the binding is complete.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rQS6lUwYom54w4iPWDXO?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Angular removes everything inside of an ng-bind when it initializes and replaces it with what ng-bind is bound to. Because your variable that your binding to ($scope.variable) is initialized as null, nothing is displayed.

Try using ng-init to add your loading text:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="'Loading...'">
     <p ng-bind="variable"></p>
</body>
```

Or: http://plnkr.co/edit/XF6OLnL8LgjkubOULP3M?p=info